# не выходит сохранить данные в json

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Делаю приложение в стиле ToDo. К сожалению я не разбираюсь в msql (а нужно было бы), раньше хранил все сохраненные данные (задачи, которые добавляю в список) в `localstorage`, это была неплохая альтернатива для хранения данных. Сейчас решил сохранять данные в `json` методом `post` и вытягивать методом `get`. `get` работает хорошо, а вот с `post` пока не сложилось..

Вот такой запрос я подаю :

```
var stringify = JSON.stringify($scope.songsForList)

       $http.post("listOfSongs.json", stringify).success(function (data, status, header, config) {
           console.log(data, status, header, config)
       }).error(function (data, status, header, config) {
           console.log(data, status, header, config)
       })
```

где `$scope.songsForList` - это массив с обьектами.

В ответ мне приходит `success`, но в `json` ничего не записалось.. Или не все так просто?

*P.S.*: В целом, я хочу, чтобы на компьютере или на сервере (не важно) у меня был файл `json`, который хранит данные и в который я могу добавлять новые данные. Это реально, и если да, то подскажите, в чем я допускаю ошибку?

Answer (score 4):

Без серверной части **это сделать невозможно**.

Нельзя обратиться к файлу с помощью метода пост, но можно добавить на сервер обработчик метода пост, которому передавать необходимые данные и который будет записывать туда, куда надо.

Конкретная реализация зависит от того, какая технология используется на сервере.

Comment: тоесть нужно использовать базу данных для этого в любом случае?

Comment: @YoroDiallo, нет, нужно использовать какие-нибудь серверные технологии: php, nodejs, cgi, asp.net и т.д. Так как они позволяют обрабатывать пост запрос и решать что делать с посланными данными